# unable to resolve class org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils grails

Tags: grails, dependency-management

I'm developing an application in grails version 2.2.1 with Eclipse, the problem is, when I run the app, i get the next message:

```
 unable to resolve class org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
```

I add the common-lang-jar to my project and as a dependency, but i get the same issue. 
What can I do?

Comment: Did you add the correct version of commons-lang library (3.0 or higher)? Please note that StringUtils class is in different package since 3.0 version. You can also press [ctrl]+[t] in Eclipse and type StringUtils to check if Eclipse sees this class in project dependencies.

Comment: How did you add the dependency? Did you put the jar in the `lib` folder? Did you add the dependency in the `BuildConfig.groovy`?

Comment: There are two versions of this lib available: lang and lang3. Could you specify location from which you downloaded the jar?

Comment: one big problem is that, the guys commited the version without a lib folder, so i created it insside WEB-INF folder. I downloaded the jar from apache, is the version 3.1 from this url: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi

Answer (score 11):

You shouldn't use jar files in the lib directory unless they're not available in a Maven repo. If it's shared code at your company or something else that isn't publicly available then you can, but try to use BuildConfig.groovy dependencies if possible.

In this case the jar is available in Maven Central, so this should work in the `dependencies` section in BuildConfig.groovy:

```
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1'
```

In the rare cases where you do need to use a jar file in the lib directory, run `grails compile --refresh-dependencies` to get it added to the classpath. Newer versions of Grails don't automatically add lib directory jars to the classpath.

Comment: don't forget to run grails clean FIRST, then grails compile --refresh-dependencies!!!

Answer (score 1):

If the answer from Burt does not work for you, make sure you have the following order in your BuildConfig:

```
repositories {
    grailsHome()
    mavenLocal()
    mavenRepo "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
    grailsPlugins()
    grailsCentral()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

It helps to right-click on the your project->Build Path->Configure Build Path->Add External JARS.